# Tablesorter hide thead in mobile

Tags: jquery, html, datatables, tablesorter

can anyone help me...
I try to hide the head in the mobile version (responsive) and I do not succeed.
Thank you
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBbNS.png)

Comment: What is the head ?

Comment: Hello Welcome to Stack overflow , Please take [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and How to Ask. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducile](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of your attempt, input and expected output.

Comment: In the reflow widget demo, under notes, you'll find css that is used to hide the thead

Comment: @Mottie ooohhhh, I had not seen it ... Thank you !!!

Answer (score 1):

The image that I have put is if headers, this one that I put now is with the headers, the information I have from this link, but I have not managed to do it.
Thanks
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dW0tQ.png)
https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-reflow.html